# html for looping through a nested interface in angular8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using Angular 8 and receiving a respons from a server

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "object": [  
    {
      "id": 1,
      "label": "creditcard",
      "image_url": "https://example.com/creditcard.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "label": "Bank Transfer",
      "account_id": 6,
      "image_url": "https://example.com/bank.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

I defined an interface which then displays:

```
export interface Details {
  id: number;
  label: string;
  image_url:string;
}

export interface Provider{
  status: number;
  object:  Details[];

}
```

The TS of the component is:

```
export class ProviderComponent implements OnInit {

  myProviders : Provider;


  constructor( private client: HttpClient,
               private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef,
               private injector: Injector) { }

  ngOnInit() : void {
    this.client.get<Provider>('rest/provider').subscribe( (data: ProviderDto) => this.myProviders = {...data});

  }

}
```

Now my question is, how do I loop through the myProviders.object so that I can display a radio button group which shows first the "credit card" and then "bank transfer" as options?
For e.g.  when i use

```
<mat-radio-group
  aria-labelledby="provider-radio-group-label"
  class="provider-radio-group" >
  <mat-radio-button class="provider-radio-button" *ngFor="let payerType of myProviders.object;" >
    {{payerType.label}}
    <br>
    <img
      [src]="payerType.image_url"
      alt="{{ payerType.label }}"
      class="img-responsive"
      style="max-height: 80px;">
    <hr>

  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

It does work, but it throws an error in the chrome console that Typeerror:Cannot read property 'object' of undefined
. The error makes sense, i guess because *ngFor is looking for an array and "object" is an array with multiple elements/variables.
How do i loop through the elements without getting any error?

Comment: myProviders?.object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is thrown before the `myProviders` is assigned the response from the asynchronous request. You could use [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-expression-operators#safe-navigation-operator) `?.` here to check if the variable is defined before trying to access it's properties.

Try the following

```html
<mat-radio-group
  aria-labelledby="provider-radio-group-label"
  class="provider-radio-group" >
  <mat-radio-button class="provider-radio-button" *ngFor="let payerType of myProviders?.object" >
    {{payerType?.label}}
    <br>
    <img
      [src]="payerType?.image_url"
      alt="{{ payerType?.label }}"
      class="img-responsive"
      style="max-height: 80px;">
    <hr>

  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Notice the `myProviders.object` replaced with `myProviders?.object`.

#### Update: `async` pipe

Instead of subscribing in the component, you could try to use the `async` pipe in the template. It also takes care of potential memory leaks.

Component

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class ProviderComponent implements OnInit {
  myProviders : Observable<ProviderDto>;      // <-- typeof `Observable`

  ngOnInit() : void {
    this.myProviders = this.this.client.get<Provider>('rest/provider');     // <-- no subscription
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(myProviders | async) as providers">
  {{ providers | json }}      <!-- check the output here and remove it later -->
  <mat-radio-group
    aria-labelledby="provider-radio-group-label"
    class="provider-radio-group" >
    <mat-radio-button class="provider-radio-button" *ngFor="let payerType of providers?.object;" >
      {{payerType?.label}}
      <br>
      <img
        [src]="payerType?.image_url"
        alt="{{ payerType?.label }}"
        class="img-responsive"
        style="max-height: 80px;">
      <hr>
    </mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I tried this, but now the results do not even load. Chrome however does not show the error message anymore. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @lopahelision: In that case, probably you aren't receiving the `object` property in the response. Try to do a `console.log(data)` inside the subscription and post the results.

Comment: {object: Array(2), status: 0}
object: Array(2)
0:
id: 3
image_url: "https://example.com/creditcard.png"
label: "creditcard"
__proto__: Object
1:
id: 4
image_url: "https://example.com/bank.png"
label: "Bank Transfer"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
status: 0
__proto__: Object

Comment: I see the `object` property. Then something else should be the issue. Try to use `async` pipe instead of the subscription. I've updated the answer. And please post a screenshot of the `{{ providers | json }}` part if it still doesn't work.